# The most efficient way of obtaining multiple averages and counts from rethinkdb

Tags: node.js, rethinkdb, rethinkdb-javascript

I am creating a web application which collects information from a form, inserts them (e.g. age, height, and weight) into a `rethinkdb` database, and then displays simple descriptive statistics via `socket.io`.

Currently, I'm using `r.expr()` to run multiple queries, e.g.

```
r.expr({
mean1: r.db(…).table(…).avg(…),
mean2: r.db(…).table(…).group(…).avg(…).mul(10).round().div(10).ungroup(),
count: r.db(…).table(…).count()
}).run(conn, (err, res) => {
...
```

to construct an object which contains the counts and averages I'm interested in and then use `io.emit()` to send them to the client for display, which is updated every time a new entry is added.

This doesn't look very efficient to me and I'm guessing there is a better way of doing this—perhaps with just one query—but I'm very inexperienced with `ReQL` and query languages in general.

Moreover, is there a better way of doing rounding with arbitrary precision or more complex numerical operations after grouping than like I did above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To perform multiple reductions at once, you can manually split them into individual `map` and `reduce` operations. Something like:

```
r.table(...).map(
    row => ({
        count: 1,
        sum: row('a'),
        groups: r.object(row('group'), {count: 1, sum: r.row('a')})
    })
).reduce(
    (left, right) => ({
        count: left('count').add(right('count')),
        sum: left('sum').add(right('sum')),
        groups: left.keys().setUnion(right.keys()).map(
                key => [key, {
                    count: left(key)('count').default(0).add(right(key)('count').default(0)),
                    sum: left(key)('sum').default(0).add(right(key)('sum').default(0))
                }]
            ).coerceTo('object')
    })
).do(
    res => ({
        count: res('count'),
        mean1: res('sum').div(res('count')),
        mean2: res('groups').coerceTo('array').map(
            pair => [pair(0), pair(1).do(x => x('sum').div(x('count')).mul(10).round().div(10)]
    }).coerceTo('object')
)
```

It may not be more efficient as-is, but could be optimized further.

You can perform [more complex mathematical operations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math) using [`r.js`](https://www.rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/js/)